# For Loop alternative Pandas Python

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

Python and Pandas rookie here! I'm trying to transpose a dataframe that contains a million records using a for loop. As you can imagine, it's painstakingly slow.
Please see below for my process and code.

There are two dataframes i'm working with:
transactions - which contains the customer_id, and the category they purchased from.

```
transactions=pandas.DataFrame({'a':['johnny','sally','maggy','lassy','johnny','sally','maggy'],
'category':['fruits','fruits','spices','veggies','veggies','spices','snacks']})
```

category_list - which contains all categories a customer could purchase from.

```
category_list=pandas.DataFrame({'category':['fruits','spices','veggies','snacks','drinks','alcohol','adult']})
```

For each customer, if the customer has (ever) made a purchase in a given category, then assign a value 1. If not, then assign value of 0.

Code:

```
cust_list = transactions['a'].unique()
final_data = pandas.DataFrame()

for i in cust_list:
    step1 = transactions[transactions.a == i]
    step1 = step1.drop_duplicates()
    step1['value'] = 1
    cat_merge = pandas.merge(step1, category_list, how='right', left_on='category', right_on='category')
    cat_merge['a'] = i
    cat_merge = cat_merge.fillna(0)
    cat_merge_transpose = pandas.DataFrame(cat_merge.transpose())
    cat_merge_transpose = cat_merge_transpose.drop(cat_merge_transpose.index[0])
    cat_merge_transpose.columns = cat_merge_transpose.iloc[0]
    cat_merge_transpose = cat_merge_transpose.drop(cat_merge_transpose.index[0])
    cat_merge_transpose.reset_index()
    cat_merge_transpose.insert(0, 'a', i)
    final_data = final_data.append(pandas.DataFrame(data = cat_merge_transpose), ignore_index=True)
```

So in this case the result would look like this:

```
print final_data
```

Any help i can get to optimize this and make it run significantly faster, with fewer lines of code will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be viewed as a pivot operation, and here we could use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
>>> df["value"] = 1
>>> P = df.pivot_table(index="a", columns="category", values="value", aggfunc=max)
>>> P.loc[:,category_list.category.unique()].fillna(0)
category  fruits  spices  veggies  snacks  drinks  alcohol  adult
a                                                                
johnny         1       0        1       0       0        0      0
lassy          0       0        1       0       0        0      0
maggy          0       1        0       1       0        0      0
sally          1       1        0       0       0        0      0
```

The `pivot_table` itself gives us

```
>>> P
category  fruits  snacks  spices  veggies
a                                        
johnny         1     NaN     NaN        1
lassy        NaN     NaN     NaN        1
maggy        NaN       1       1      NaN
sally          1     NaN       1      NaN
```

and then we index into this using all the category columns (including the ones which weren't seen), calling `fillna` to replace the NaNs with 0.

Comment: Wow! This is crazy. Even with significantly less code!

Comment: I want to give both the tick but i'm going to give the tick to the one that runs fastest. You guys are awesome.

Comment: Yours took less than a minute for almost 2 million records! I give the nod to DSM for the performance! Other solution took 10 minutes, which is still 100,000 times faster than my for loop! Stack rocks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get a unique list of all category items.
categories = category_list.category.unique().tolist()

# For transactions with a given customer matching any category, assign a value of one.
transactions['value'] = transactions.groupby('a').category.transform(
                            lambda s: s.isin(categories).any()).astype(int)
output = transactions.groupby(['a', 'category']).max().unstack().fillna(0)
output.columns = output.columns.droplevel()
zero_cols = [c for c in categories if c not in output]
for col in zero_cols:
    output[col] = 0
>>> output
category  fruits  snacks  spices  veggies  drinks  alcohol  adult
a                                                                
johnny         1       0       0        1       0        0      0
lassy          0       0       0        1       0        0      0
maggy          0       1       1        0       0        0      0
sally          1       0       1        0       0        0      0
```

Comment: Thanks. This however doesn't get me the transposed matrix.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Used your solution against my sample data and the results are not the same as the code i've posted. My final output should be the same as what I have in final_data

Comment: Sorry about that. The values are if you've ordered from that category. Thanks.